# Azure Logic app: "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'MyProcName', database 'dbName', schema 'dbo'."

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to call a stored procedure from the Azure logic app
but I am getting below error,

```
"body": {
    "status": 403,
    "message": "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'MyProcName', database 'dbName', schema 'dbo'.\r\nclientRequestId:id,
    "error": {
        "message": "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'MyProcName', database 'dbName', schema 'dbo'."
    },
    "source": "sql-wus2.azconn-wus2.p.azurewebsites.net"
```

but I can execute it from SSMS.

what is going wrong here?

Do I need to get execute permission for logic app resource group or subscription which I am using for the logic app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means, the user you are connecting to the DB with does not have appropriate permissions, in this case the EXECUTE permission.

If it's from a logic app, you must be connecting via either:

- An Azure AD user OR A database user

Check your connection string you will know; does it have username and password etc?

In either case EXECUTE permission needs to be given to the user.

```
GRANT Execute ON [dbName].MyProcName TO [the-user-trying-connect-to-the-db]
```

Comment: I used Azure AD authentication and then I was able to execute stored procedure from logic app. But in future suppose my credentials become invalid because I am moving to any other project. Then again that logic app will give error while executing the stored procedure?

Comment: and this is connectionstring -> Server=tcp:serverdetails,port ;Initial Catalog=dbName;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: @Explorer If you use the same AD user to connect to the db (in the new logic app) then should not be a problem.  What ever user you are connecting to the db with needs to have the access

Comment: I am just confused, in the future, after completing the project, the client will revoke my access to the database for my id, then it will work or not? because my id will no longer exist for authentication.

Comment: @Explorer when in dev you can use your id etc, but when it comes to actual production, you would typically have another user connecting to the db and this user is set via an automation pipeline (Github Actions or Azure Devops pipeline).  This can either be a SQL user and passoword stored in a keyvault or a differnt AD user